# Type conversion rule - Converting a type to its underlying type

Tags: go

Got into below scenario amidst copying one object(type1) members to another object(type2) member:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SomeType string

func main() {
    source := SomeType("abc")
    dest := string(source) // this works 
    fmt.Println(dest)
}
```

---

For this type conversion(`string(source)`), which rule from Go spec is applied, for conversion to underlying type?

Comment: The conversion rules are all in the section aptly titled [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read about [conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), you'll see the rules for non-constant conversions. The first one applies:

> - x is [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to T.

and links to the section on [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability). In turn, the relevant bit there is:

> - x's type V and T have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of V or T is not a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type.